# Exception "Error Decrpyting Data"when opening drawing

Tags: c#, autocad

I have a program that does batch processing on some drawings.  One of the drawings throws an exception "Error Decrypting Data" when I try to open it.  This drawing in particular was generated by a third-party tool other than AutoCAD.  In addition, this problem only occurs in AutoCAD 2011.  In AutoCAD 2010 it prompts the user that the file was generated outside of AutoCAD but they can click and the batch will continue.  I've tried opening it using both the managed .NET API and the COM Interop API but both give the same error.

Here is a post from the AutoCAD formus though it didn't provide me with a solution:

http://forums.autodesk.com/t5/NET/Error-Decrypting-Data-Acad-2011/td-p/2661762/highlight/true

Managed API

```
string drawingFilePath = @"C:\Drawings\MyDrawing.dwg";
Application.DocumentManager.Open(drawingFilePath, false);
```

COM Interop

```
string drawingFilePath = @"C:\Drawings\MyDrawing.dwg";
Object comAutoCAD = Application.AcadApplication;
Object comDocuments = comAutoCAD.GetType().InvokeMember("Documents", BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, comAutoCAD, new object[] { });

Object comDocument = comDocuments.GetType().InvokeMember("Open", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, comDocuments,
    new object[] { drawingFilePath, false, Type.Missing });
Document.FromAcadDocument(comDocument);
```

Comment: After further testing I found that just modifying the drawing through opening the database with the Database.ReadDwgFile method will NOT throw any errors and I can do my operation just fine.  However, it only worked for this particular drawing because I don't need to do any operations on it that require opening the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone from the AutoCAD forums posted an answer that works for me.

http://forums.autodesk.com/t5/NET/Error-Decrypting-Data-Acad-2011/td-p/2661762/page/2

Here is an example:

```
const string systemVar_DwgCheck = "DWGCHECK";
Int16 dwgCheckPrevious = (Int16)Application.GetSystemVariable(systemVar_DwgCheck);
Application.SetSystemVariable(systemVar_DwgCheck, 2);

Document document = Application.DocumentManager.Open(@"C:\Drawings\MyDrawing.dwg", false);
// Do stuff...

Application.SetSystemVariable(systemVar_DwgCheck, dwgCheckPrevious);
```